# Arraylist implementing text but not images

Tags: java, android, image, arraylist, text

I have setup a simple getter and setter which is used to set images as well as text to my recycler view layout but currently at the moment it's only setting the text that is being set but not the image.

When running the code it doesn't display any errors, i'm continuing to search for a resolution.

Modal Class...

```
public AlarmCreationModal(String mTitle, Bitmap mImage, int mType) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mType = mType;
    this.mImage = mImage;
}

private String mTitle;

public Bitmap getmImage() {
    return mImage;
}

public void setmImage(Bitmap mImage) {
    this.mImage = mImage;
}

private Bitmap mImage;

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public int getmType() {
    return mType;
}

public void setmType(int mType) {
    this.mType = mType;
}
```

Setting the information....

```
List<AlarmCreationModal> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new AlarmCreationModal("Contacts", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(),R.drawable.ic_menu_camera), AlarmCreationModal.Row0));
```

Retrieving the information inside of my recycler view adapter....

```
((CustomViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getmTitle());
((CustomViewHolder) holder).mImage.setImageBitmap(object.getmImage());
```

Thank you

Comment: please post AlarmCreationModal calss

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 10 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated as requested

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

I changed the `Bitmap` to an int within my `Modal Class`

```
public AlarmCreationModal(String mTitle, int mImage, int mType) {
this.mTitle = mTitle;
this.mType = mType;
this.mImage = mImage;
}
```

Secondly setting the information

```
List<AlarmCreationModal> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new AlarmCreationModal("Contacts", R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, AlarmCreationModal.Row0));
```

Thirdly retrieving the information on the adapter

```
((CustomViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getmTitle());
((CustomViewHolder) holder).mImage.setImageResource(object.getmImage());
```